Github left file pane disappeared and no way to get it back
The title says it all. In Github when browsing code somehow the left file pane disappeared. And I can't find any way to get it back.
This question may seem a duplicate of Github code browsing left navigation panel disappears . The question had not been answered. Besides, when I click on the File icon (next to the branch name) I get a pop-up file pane, obscuring the code pane.
I just want to have the file pane docked on the left of the code pane. As it was. I have no idea what triggered the disappearance.
Note that in the situation where the file pane still is there, I can make it disappear and appear again by clicking on the icon next to the branch name. Now in the situation where it has disappeared I see a blue dot on this icon and I get a pop-up on clicking it.
This is the situation now:

And this is how it WAS. Fortunately I still have another tab open in my browser.

Using the back button does not show the file pane again. And if I leave Github and enter this project again, the file pane is still missing.

Click on the button to the left of Files, above the branch selector.

I wrote that did not work. It produces a pop-up. Not the docked file pane

Click on the file pane icon with the blue dot. A file pane pop-up appears. On that pop-up, select a branch. In this case Master.
The docked file pane will return.
Addition: If there is no blue dot on the file icon, still the pop-up file pane might appear. In that case (no blue dot) be sure to close the  symbols panel first if it is open.

Just a heads up that you can mark your own answer as correct if it helps to solve your problem :P
